# File not found errors when trying to setup asciidoctor

Tags: build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, asciidoctor

I am trying to configure asciidoctor with Spring restdocs. I am upgrading it from `org.asciidoctor.convert` to `org.asciidoctor.jvm.convert` but am getting the error that it can't find the pages and load the snippets. And based on the errors I get it doesn't do anything with the configurations I set inside my gradle build file. I have tried to add `asciidoctorExtensions` in order to replace the deprecated `asciidoctor` but nothing seems to work.

The errors:

```
jun. 18, 2021 2:56:10 P.M. uri:classloader:/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.10/lib/asciidoctor/substitutors.rb sub_macros
INFO: possible invalid reference: synchronization
jun. 18, 2021 2:56:10 P.M. uri:classloader:/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.10/lib/asciidoctor/reader.rb preprocess_include_directive
SEVERE: errors.adoc: line 23: include file not found: C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/{snippets}/send not serializable date/response-body.adoc
include file not found: C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/{snippets}/send not serializable date/response-body.adoc :: errors.adoc :: C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/src/main/docs/errors.adoc:23 (uri:classloader:/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.10/lib/asciidoctor/reader.rb:preprocess_include_directive)
jun. 18, 2021 2:56:10 P.M. uri:classloader:/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.10/lib/asciidoctor/reader.rb preprocess_include_directive
SEVERE: index.adoc: line 51: include file not found: C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/synchronization.adoc
include file not found: C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/synchronization.adoc :: index.adoc :: C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/src/main/docs/index.adoc:51 (uri:classloader:/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.10/lib/asciidoctor/reader.rb:preprocess_include_directive)
jun. 18, 2021 2:56:10 P.M. uri:classloader:/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.10/lib/asciidoctor/reader.rb preprocess_include_directive
SEVERE: index.adoc: line 67: include file not found: C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/errors.adoc
include file not found: C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/errors.adoc :: index.adoc :: C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/src/main/docs/index.adoc:67 (uri:classloader:/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.10/lib/asciidoctor/reader.rb:preprocess_include_directive)
jun. 18, 2021 2:56:10 P.M. uri:classloader:/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.10/lib/asciidoctor/reader.rb preprocess_include_directive
SEVERE: index.adoc: line 78: include file not found: C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/app-user-settings.adoc
include file not found: C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/app-user-settings.adoc :: index.adoc :: C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/src/main/docs/index.adoc:78 (uri:classloader:/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.10/lib/asciidoctor/reader.rb:preprocess_include_directive)
jun. 18, 2021 2:56:10 P.M. uri:classloader:/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.10/lib/asciidoctor/reader.rb preprocess_include_directive
SEVERE: index.adoc: line 82: include file not found: C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/miscellaneous-calls.adoc
include file not found: C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/miscellaneous-calls.adoc :: index.adoc :: C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/src/main/docs/index.adoc:82 (uri:classloader:/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.10/lib/asciidoctor/reader.rb:preprocess_include_directive)
jun. 18, 2021 2:56:10 P.M. uri:classloader:/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.10/lib/asciidoctor/converter/html5.rb convert_document
WARNING: C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/src/main/docs/index.adoc: stylesheet does not exist or cannot be read: C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/riak.css
jun. 18, 2021 2:56:10 P.M. uri:classloader:/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.10/lib/asciidoctor/substitutors.rb sub_macros
C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/src/main/docs/index.adoc: stylesheet does not exist or cannot be read: C:/Users/User/Documents/Projects/Trips/riak.css
```

Build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id("org.asciidoctor.jvm.convert") version "3.3.2"
    ...
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.10"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.10"
}

val asciidoctorExtensions: Configuration by configurations.creating
dependencies {
    ...

    asciidoctorExtensions("org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-asciidoctor")
}


val snippetsDir by extra { file("build/generated-snippets") }
tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    outputs.dir(snippetsDir)

    mustRunAfter(tasks.flywayMigrate.get())
}

tasks.asciidoctor {
    asciidoctorExtensions
    sourceDir("src/main/docs")
    inputs.dir(snippetsDir)
    attributes["snippets"] = file(snippetsDir)
    attributes["environment-${project.properties["spring.profiles.active"]}"] = true
    dependsOn(tasks.test.get())
}
```

Index.adoc:

```
:toc: left
:sectlinks:
:sectnums:
:sectnumlevels: 5
:toc: left
:toclevels: 2
:page-layout: docs
:source-highlighter: highlightjs
:stylesheet: riak.css

...

include::errors.adoc[]
include::synchronization.adoc[]
include::app-user-settings.adoc[]
```

Errors.adoc:

```
[[errors, Errors]]
== Errors
...

[[not_serializable_date]]
==== Incorrect dateformat
include::{snippets}/send{sp}not{sp}serializable{sp}date/response-body.adoc[]
```

App-user-settings.adoc:

```
[[app_user_settings, AppUserSetting(s)]]
== AppUserSetting(s)

[.lead]
...

=== Create
...

[.tabs]
--
operation::create{sp}a{sp}app{sp}user{sp}setting[snippets='request-fields,request-body,curl-request,http-request,httpie-request']
--
```

What am I doing wrong / what do I have to change to have it work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a working example for Gradle here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs-samples/blob/main/restful-notes-spring-hateoas/build.gradle

Please note: There is no need to set the *snippets* attribute: It is set automatically by the spring-restdocs-asciidoctor extension.